# Traefik dashboard refuses connection using minikube

Tags: traefik, minikube

I try to deploy Traefik (v1.7) to local minikube cluster using helm

```
helm install --values values.yml stable/traefik
```

values.yml:

```
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: dashboard.localhost
kubernetes:
  namespaces:
    - default
    - kube-system
```

I added dashboard.localhost to the /etc/hosts file
But I can not get access to the dashboard.

```
curl http://dashboard.localhost:31745/
404 page not found

curl http://dashboard.localhost/
```

no response...

In a browser:
[image: Browser ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

```
minikube service list
|----------------------|-----------------------------------|--------------------------------|-----|
|      NAMESPACE       |               NAME                |          TARGET PORT           | URL |
|----------------------|-----------------------------------|--------------------------------|-----|
| default              | coiled-cardinal-traefik           | http://192.168.99.111:31731    |
|                      |                                   | http://192.168.99.111:31745    |
| default              | coiled-cardinal-traefik-dashboard | No node port                   |
| default              | kubernetes                        | No node port                   |
| default              | traefik-web-ui                    | No node port                   |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                          | No node port                   |
| kube-system          | tiller-deploy                     | No node port                   |
| kube-system          | traefik-web-ui                    | No node port                   |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper         | No node port                   |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard              | No node port                   |
|----------------------|-----------------------------------|--------------------------------|-----|


kubectl get svc coiled-cardinal-traefik --namespace default -w
NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
coiled-cardinal-traefik   LoadBalancer   10.111.40.100   <pending>     80:31731/TCP,443:31745/TCP   36m
```

any idaes?

UPDATE:

A created and applied two services according to the Traefik docs. 
My variant:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

Traefic 1.7 docs variant:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik-ui.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: 80
```

My /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   test
192.168.99.111  dashboard.localhost
192.168.99.111 traefik-ui.minikube
```

open http://traefik-ui.minikube
The end result is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT...

Answer (score 0):

To access dashboard you have to create two services, as explained in [traefik docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/user-guide/kubernetes/#submitting-an-ingress-to-the-cluster):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik-ui.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: 80
```

and then add an entry in `etc/hosts:`

```
echo "$(minikube ip) traefik-ui.minikube" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: And I did it. apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web

Comment: In `values.yaml` uncomment (if commented) and change `serviceType:` to `LoadBalancer`